# hadoop command to get size of multiple folders in one go

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to figure out hadoop command to get size of multiple folders/directries in one go.

I am able to get size of individual folder by below command:
`hadoop fs -du -s -h <directory>`

As in this case there are further sub directories are present.

Comment: You can try `hadoop fs -count` to see if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a Hadoop command to do that. But you could just combine it with other shell programs. For example:

```
hadoop fs -ls -R <directory> | grep "^d" | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs hadoop fs -du
```

This will execute `hadoop fs -du` for each directory within `<directory>`.

A breakdown of the above command:

- `hadoop fs -ls -R <directory> | grep "^d"` gets you all the directories inside `<directory>`.
- `awk '{print $NF}'` gets the directory name.
- `xargs hadoop fs -du` executes `hadoop fs -du` for each directory name.

Also, it could be useful to use `hadoop fs -du -s` rather than `hadoop fs -du` if you're only interested in the size of the directories.